# Problem filling between two plots

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I wanted to be able to plot two curves will fills like this:

[image]

This is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin = 0, axis x line = bottom, axis y line=middle, legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot [name path=A, domain=-5:5,cyan, thick]{x^2 + 2*x + 2};
\addplot [name path=B, domain=0:10,orange,thick]{2*x + 2};
\legend{$f(x)$, $g(x)$}
\addplot[blue!20] fill between[of=A and B];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `soft clip` option in first and second graphs, and a third path in second graph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin = 0, axis x line = bottom, axis y line=middle, 
             legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot [name path=A, domain=-5:5,cyan, thick]{x^2 + 2*x + 2};
\addplot [name path=B, domain=0:10,orange,thick]{2*x + 2};
\legend{$f(x)$, $g(x)$}
\addplot[blue!20] fill between[of=A and B, 
       soft clip={domain={0:10}}]; %<--------- added
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin = 0, axis x line = bottom, axis y line=middle, 
             legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot [name path=A, domain=-5:5,cyan, thick]{x^2 + 2*x + 2};
\addplot [name path=B, domain=0:10,orange,thick]{2*x + 2};
\legend{$f(x)$, $g(x)$}

\path [name path=yaxis] (0,0)--(0,35);  %<---- third path

\addplot[blue!20] fill between[of=A and B, 
         soft clip={domain={0:10}}]; %<---- added soft clip
\addplot[blue!20] fill between[of=A and yaxis, 
         soft clip={domain={0:10}}];  %<----- added second region
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]